# Upsampling an Image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, edge-detection

I have a basic question.

1. What are the advantages of upsampling an Image?
2. Does it help me in edge detection?

I have not found much useful information on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the image.  It can help if you have extremely jagged edges.  At the worst it does nothing.  So, you pay in processing time for a potential improvement.

Answer (score 0):

> Usually we need to convert an image to a size different than its
>   original.

For this, there are two possible options:

1. Upsize the image (zoom in)
2. Downsize it (zoom out)

As an example, you could want to do your calculations (e.g. segmentation) on a downsized Image, later on you want to work on the original Image data again, so you upsize your Output (e.g. Segmentation mask) again.

> Finding better results on upsized Images when applying edge detection
>   can rise from the following:

With edge detectors (e.g. canny, not only gradient computation) a blurring algorithm is usually connected. If you use some sort of blurring mask in preprocessing, it is possible that you can obtain similar behavior by its modification (decreasing, or increasing power of blurring) as in the case of image resize.